# C++ copy constructor, assignment 'operator='

Tags: c++, copy, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I'm trying to make a copy constructor or = operator.
If I define a matrix named A, another as B and C and use the '=' operator as:

A=B

it performs well, However if i use like:

A=B+C 
i get this error: no matching function for '='.

The point is when I change the symbol(=) to (==) it works well,even in the case of A == B+C, however by using only the equality sign(=) it doesn't work!
any ideas?

In the header file:

```
Simple2DMatrixD (const Simple2DMatrixD& matrixA)
{
   numRows = matrixA.numRows;
   numCols = matrixA.numCols;

   dataArray = new double[numRows * numCols];

   for (int iX = 0; iX < numRows; iX++)
   {
       for (int iY = 0; iY < numCols; iY++)
       {
           dataArray[(iX * numRows) + iY] = matrixA.getElement(iX,iY) ;
       }
   }
}


Simple2DMatrixD & assign (const Simple2DMatrixD & matrixB);
Simple2DMatrixD & sum (const Simple2DMatrixD & matrixA, const Simple2DMatrixD & matrixB);
```

// ADDITION OPERATOR

```
friend Simple2DMatrixD operator+ (Simple2DMatrixD & matrixA, Simple2DMatrixD & matrixB)
{
    Simple2DMatrixD matrixTemp(matrixA.numRows, matrixA.numCols);

    matrixTemp.sum(matrixA, matrixB);
    return (matrixTemp);
}
```

// ASSIGNMENT OPERATOR

```
Simple2DMatrixD & operator= (const Simple2DMatrixD & matrixB)
{
    this->assign(matrixB);
    return (*this);
}
```

// and in the source file:

```
Simple2DMatrixD & Simple2DMatrixD::assign (const Simple2DMatrixD & matrixB)
{

for (int r = 0; r < numRows; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < numCols; c++)
    {
        this->setElement(r, c, matrixB.getElement(r, c));
    }
}
return (*this);

}
```

// MATRICES ADDITION

```
Simple2DMatrixD & Simple2DMatrixD::sum (const Simple2DMatrixD & matrixA, const Simple2DMatrixD &         
matrixB)
{

// TODO REPLACE WITH COMPAREDIMENSION FUNCTION
if ((this->numRows == matrixB.numRows)
    && (this->numCols == matrixB.numCols)
    )
{

    for (int r = 0; r < matrixA.numRows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < matrixA.numCols; c++)
        {
            this->setElement(r, c, matrixA.getElement(r, c) + matrixB.getElement(r, c));
        }
    }
    return (*this);
}
else

{
    throw " Dimensions does not match!";
}

}
```

Comment: Change the addition operator to take `const` references. Also, show real code. Particularly, where are members defined (inline in the class definition or separately, in an implementation file?)

Comment: Could you reduce this to a complete, minimal test case that demonstrates the error? I can't reproduce it when I try to stitch your fragments into something compilable.

Comment: what that `friend` is doing before the definition of the `operator+`?

Comment: @40two most likely declaring the addition operator as a friend.

Comment: @40two: Declaring it a friend of the class, so that it can access private members while not being a member.

Comment: Unrelated to this specific problem, but if you made `dataArray` a `std::vector<double>` and then used `resize`, you'd avoid having to do your own memory management.

Answer (score 1):

You are abusing `friend` specifier. You'll either have to declare the `operator+` outside class's definition like this:

```
inline Simple2DMatrixD operator+(Simple2DMatrixD & matrixA, Simple2DMatrixD & matrixB)
{
  Simple2DMatrixD matrixTemp(matrixA.numRows, matrixA.numCols);

  matrixTemp.sum(matrixA, matrixB);
  return (matrixTemp);
}
```

And declare it as a friend in class `Simple2DMatrixD`:

```
class Simple2DMatrixD {
  friend Simple2DMatrixD operator+ (Simple2DMatrixD & matrixA, Simple2DMatrixD & matrixB);
  ...
};
```

Or you can declare it inside class's definition like this:

```
class Simple2DMatrixD {
  ...

  Simple2DMatrixD operator+(Simple2DMatrixD const &rhs)
  {
    Simple2DMatrixD matrixTemp(rhs.numRows, rhs.numCols);
    matrixTemp.sum(*this, rhs);
    return (matrixTemp);
  }

  ...
};
```

`friend` outside class's definition is an invalid specifier.

Comment: Your first example would require an `inline`. Also, you are missing one valid option: `friend` function defined inside of the class definition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. i tried but i still get this error: no match for 'operator =' in math_utils::Simple2DMatrix::operator+(const math_utils::Simple2DMatrix&)((*(const math_utils::Simple2DMatrix*)(& mB.math_utils::Matrix3x3::<anonymous>)))' . The thing that i mentioned before and makes me so confused is when with the same definitions i define the assignment sign as '==' it works!!! Do you have any ideas that why this happens? I will really appreciate your assistance. @40two

Comment: @juanchopanza I tried all still the same error. im really confused!

Comment: @user3506463 Read the first two comments to your question, and act on them.

Comment: @juanchopanza i tried with const reference too! same error! By i dont understand why! do you think the symbol '=' should be defined in a specific way? why '==' works as an assignment operator very well!

Comment: @user3506463 post a minimal example that reproduces the problem

Comment: @juanchopanza i have two matrices, mA and mB as:                double valA[] =
        { -2, 1, 8, 0, 3, 1, -1, -2, -3 };
double valB[] =
        { -1, -2, 1, 4, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1 };                                            
if i write mC = mA; I will have a result mC which is equal to mA. Till now all worked well. However if i want mC = mA+mB; i get an error of no match for 'operator=' in 'mC =.... , now if i changed my operator= in the heading( as i wrote before) to operator==, it works! i mean both examples i wrote they perform well! thank you very much indeed!

Comment: @user3506463 You are doing many things wrong in your code. The problem you had was one of them. I've coded an example to get some ideas of how your code should be. It's not perfect (e.g., I would use a std::array instead of dynamic memory). Take a look http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b17ce45c0675ecd6 keep calm and program in C++ :)

Answer (score 0):

my intuition says me that your `const` correctness is faulty somewhere. please post the complete error message.

declare member function that does not change the object as `const`.

```
struct A
{
  float retunrsSomethingButDoesNotChangesA()const; // <- note the const
};

// in cpp:
float A::retunrsSomethingButDoesNotChangesA()const // <- note the const
{
  return 5.5f;
}
```

and make reference parameter of functions `const` if the function does not change them.